# Is this nginx config with proxy setup safe?

Tags: nginx

I've set up a Node/Express HTTPS / SSL server using LetsEncrypt for the certificates, running on port 3000. It works and I can access it via `www.example.com:3000`. But I really want to be able to access it directly from `www.example.com`.

I managed to get this working (see my code below) by creating my own nginx configuration and running `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;                        // *

        location / {
                allow all;                    // *
        }
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        allow all;                            // *
    }
}
```

I adapted the second server from a Certbot auto-generated server when I set up my certificate.

I'm a toal newb to nginx config files. Can anyone advise on the safety of my implementation? Am I missing anything? I'm wondering in particular about the lines I've appened `// *` to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you are using the latest version of `nginx`.
- [Review the SSL ciphers you have enabled with `nginx`](https://sslciphers.com/) - to avoid downgrade attacks you want to disable some out-of-date ones.
- Do you really need it accessible on both plaintext port 80 and 443?  If you don't have a specific need for non-encrypted HTTP, I'd remove the first block entirely and make the second block your `default server`.
- Anything on well-known public HTTP/HTTPS ports will get regular bot scans from many countries looking for recent CVE vulnerabilities.

  - You should consider not hosting your application at the root of the URL, but reverse proxy to a path and at something like `https://yourdomain.example.com/codeword` where "`codeword`" is something unique and not connected to anything remotely related to generic or specific computer/Internet applications or administration concepts.  For example, `https://yourdomain.example.com/admin` or `https://yourdomain.example.com/app`  will likely get hit with scans, but `https://yourdomain.example.com/kittens` probably wouldn't.
  - You may consider learning about the `ngx_http_geoip_module` and [only allowing expected countries](https://devcoops.com/block-visitors-by-country-in-nginx/).
  - [HTTP Basic Auth](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) can also be used to block anyone from causing any web app code to run on your server without being able to tell nginx the basic auth username/password.